# Web API - Collate and send data to user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a web service built using ASP MVC Web API, I wish to collate all the users information into a file transfer that to the front end, in this case a ASP website. Just want to know is it better practise to collate and produce the document i.e. a .txt file or .PDF on web service side or collate information and return it to the client where they will then create the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its better to do it at the server side so that other applications are able to reuse your service methods and not worry about creating documents. Also creating a PDF requires libraries which are better to be installed and maintained at the server side. If required, you can create another service method which sends raw user information so that client can do whatever it needs using that info.

Comment: Also, if collation takes much time, you can make the method async.